# Prove that all the sheep are the same weight

Tags: mathematics

A farmer has a certain number of sheep.

Whichever single sheep you pick, you can always divide the other remaining sheep in two groups which have the same number weight and the same number of sheep.

Can you prove that all sheep are the same weight?

Comment: [We've had this puzzle before.](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/7882/4551)

Comment: @DrunkWolf Huh, it still looks to me like you are removing only one sheep?

Comment: It is not correct, you did not answer the question for real numbers.

Comment: @BlueTrin http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002267/after-removing-any-part-the-rest-can-be-split-evenly-consequences this is the same on math.stack , it features a great answer by Christian Blatter that I don't think any of us will improve on.

Comment: Already asked and answered very accurately in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002267/after-removing-any-part-the-rest-can-be-split-evenly-consequences

Comment: Could we have this question removed? I keep coming back to it and getting reminded that it's already solved in three different places already. It also has a good ranking in 'unanswered'.